# Move NopCommerce Plugin Project location

Tags: visual-studio, plugins, nopcommerce

Getting error after moving plugin location from root to plugins director. Could you help me to resolve it. I can create new but don't want to create new one.

```
E:\NopCommerce\Nop.Plugin.Notification.Email
\Nop.Plugin.Notification.Email.csproj : error  : The project file could not be 
loaded. Could not find a part of the path 'E:\NopCommerce
\Nop.Plugin.Notification.Email\Nop.Plugin.Notification.Email.csproj'.  
E:\NopCommerce\Nop.Plugin.Notification.Email\Nop.Plugin.Notification.Email.csproj
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you just moved the plugin into a new directory without changing the solution file.

You have to fix the path inside of the .sln file. Otherwise the solution cannot find the project and thus it cannot be loaded properly.

Comment: This solution also works after renaming projects as I just did. Thanks!